with the node package "commander", "args" and others, my options are never recognized when running it from npm run
When using an args processor like commander, I can get arguments, but not options if I make a script for it.
package.json...
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "This app's CLI is going to have problems",
  "main": "src/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "node src/app.js",
    "command": "node src/cli.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "^12.1.0"
  },
}


... this works fine if I run npm run command foo; src/cli.js gets passed foo as an arg. However, if I run npm run command foo --force; the --force option is never passed.

npm will process and remove all options from the command-line, whether recognised or not. You can stop the option processing (so the arguments remain) by using an argument of --. This is a common pattern supported by many cli programs.
So in your case you could use:
npm run -- command foo --force

The work-around is mentioned in the npm documentation for npm-run-script:

Any positional arguments are passed to the specified script. Use -- to pass --prefixed flags and options which would otherwise be parsed by npm.
For example:
npm run test -- --grep="pattern"

It causes so much confusion that Commander also has a specific section in its README for npm-run-script

By default, when you call your program using run-script, npm will parse any options on the command-line and they will not reach your program. Use
-- to stop the npm option parsing and pass through all the arguments.
The synopsis for npm run-script explicitly shows the -- for this reason:
npm run-script <command> [-- <args>]


Wow thanks! A valuable piece of information!

I spent hours on this. npm captures all - and -- prefixed options, so your script will never have a chance to see them. Strangely this doesn't seem very well documented, and GitHub CoPilot, ChatGPT and Claude all fail to recognize what's happening.
Instead, use the bin option, or relent to non-option commands if you must use them in an npm script.
